# How to fix an endless rendering / measure loop with WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, freeze

I have the following XAML code implementing a data grid with DirectionalNavigation = Cycle.

```
 <DataGrid
    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"  
    x:Name="ToolPathGridView"
    VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
    ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    SelectionUnit="FullRow"
    CanUserDeleteRows="False"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    ItemsSource="{Binding 
        ToolPath.ToolPath, 
        Mode=OneWay,
        Converter={StaticResource IndexedConverter}}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">

  <DataGrid.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush 
       x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" 
       Color="DarkGray"/>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
             Id
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}"/>
             </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource T9N},             
                        Path=SwivelAxis}" />

             </StackPanel>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>

                 <Label Content="{Binding Value.ToolAxes.Swivel}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource T9N},     
                        Path=ChuckAxis}" />

             </StackPanel>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>

                 <Label Content="{Binding Value.ToolAxes.Chuck}"/>
             </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource T9N}, 
                            Path=VerticalAxis}" />

             </StackPanel>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <Label Content="{Binding Value.ToolAxes.Vertical}"/>
             </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image: datagrid]

Using the arrow keys I can move up and down the rows.

If the last row in the data-grid is selected, as above, and the **down arrow** is pressed then the **first row** in the list should become selected. However WPF goes into an endless measure / arrange loop.

I previously had custom user controls in each of the cell templates but have removed them and replaced them with plain labels just in case my controls were behaving badly.

Does anybody have an idea if this is a bug in WPF or a problem with my usage of the data grid?

Comment: Is it possible that the first row is being selected over and over? Perhaps you should step through your code and find out where things are going wrong.

Comment: The loop is not in my code. I don't handle the arrow key events. It is all internal to WPF